# No output in speech recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech

I've seen over 5 yt tutorials on how to work with speech recognition modules but when i try them,I just get no output!

```
import speech_recognition as sr

root = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source :
    print('Listening:')
    audio = root.listen(source)
text = root.recognize_google(audio)
print(text)
```

this is my code.
it prints `Listening:` but If I talk to it nothing more gets printed.
Im sure that my microphone is okay because I tested windows default speek recognition and it worked with no errors.
also I installed all the libraies required so I don't think that would be much of a problem too.

Comment: If the exact same code works for other people, then you need to provide instructions someone can follow to make it fail the same way it fails for you to have a [mre]. A bug that nobody else can make happen is a bug we can't reproduce, so we can't test our answers or provide non-speculative diagnosis.

Comment: BTW, I'd start by looking at which audio devices the code binds to by default -- if it binds to a different microphone, there's your bug. If that microphone's gain is turned down, _there's_ your bug. There's quite a bit of work to do to rule out environmental causes.

Comment: A good place to start before writing your own code at all is to try to make sure [the upstream example code](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/microphone_recognition.py) works when run without changes. If the upstream example fails the same way, you know it isn't a code problem (and non-code problems aren't on-topic here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should give the `listen()` function a time duration so that the Recognizer can parse your saying.

> The `phrase_time_limit` parameter is the maximum number of seconds that this will allow a phrase to continue before stopping and returning the part of the phrase processed before the time limit was reached. The resulting audio will be the phrase cut off at the time limit. - based on [the official docs](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#recognizer_instancelistensource-audiosource-timeout-unionfloat-none--none-phrase_time_limit-unionfloat-none--none-snowboy_configuration-uniontuplestr-iterablestr-none--none---audiodata)

```
import speech_recognition as sr  
                                                                
root = sr.Recognizer()                                                                                   
with sr.Microphone(device_index=0) as source:                                                                       
    print("Speak:")                                                                                   
    audio = root.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=5.0) # in seconds  
    # or you can try this ...
    # audio = root.record(source, duration = 5.0)

print("You said " + root.recognize_google(audio))
```

Comment: How so? `root.listen` is used in https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/microphone_recognition.py, so it's clearly usable in similar scenarios. What distinguishes that upstream example from the OP's use case?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your comment. I modify the code and use the same function (i.e., `root.listen`)